# Gearman Worker immediately disconnected

Tags: php, macos, gearman

I'm having a bit of a struggle with Gearman on OSX. I've setup gearman with brew :

```
brew install gearman php55-gearman
```

When I launch my worker, it gets disconnected directly. gearmand log:

```
INFO 2015-04-26 22:07:57.000000 [  main ] Accepted connection from 127.0.0.1:55360
INFO 2015-04-26 22:07:57.000000 [     4 ] Peer connection has called close()
INFO 2015-04-26 22:07:57.000000 [     4 ] Disconnected 127.0.0.1:55360
INFO 2015-04-26 22:07:57.000000 [     4 ] Gear connection disconnected: -:-
```

And I've got no errors on my script :

```
...
@worker\servers :

    #localhost - 127.0.0.1:4730

@Worker\description :

    Data file Worker

[2015-04-27 00:07:57] loaded. Ctrl+C to break
## (back to shell)
```

gearman versions are :

- server: gearmand 1.1.12 - https://bugs.launchpad.net/gearmand
- lib : libgearman version => 1.1.12

I've got a Debian setup working on a prod env with these versions installed through apt packages :

- server: gearmand 1.1.12 - https://bugs.launchpad.net/gearmand
- lib : libgearman version => 0.33

Has anyone encountered the same errors ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not from gearman or the lib but the Symfony Bundle I was using. (cf https://github.com/mmoreram/GearmanBundle/issues/143).